# AFNetworking is converting my doubles into quoted strings when formatting JSON

Tags: ios, json, encoding, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I'm trying to use AFNetworking on a project for the first time and having trouble setting turning float `double` into a JSON parameter. I'm creating a NSDictionary with key value pairs. NSDictionary only accepts objects so double values are created with `[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 37.234567]`. All good. But when I dump the dictionary I get:

```
Dict: {
    day = Wednesday;
    user = Meltemi;
    lat = "37.234567";
    long = "-120.123456";
}
```

which, when submitted as an HTTP request, become: `lat=%2237.234567%22` and `long=%22-120.123456%22` and Sinatra is receiving them as:

```
params: { "lat"=>"\"37.750256\"", "long"=>"\"-120.123456\"", ... }
```

What I want/need:

```
Dict: {
    day = Wednesday;
    user = Meltemi;
    lat = 37.234567;
    long = -120.123456;
}
```

The API may very well not be fault tolerant but **how to force AFNetworking to lose the quotation marks?**

**Edit: adding AFHTTPClient subclass's initializer:**

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if(!self) return nil;
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pwd"];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];  // TODO: right place for this?

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Does NSDecimalNumber improve things?

Comment: Appreciate the idea but I don't see how it would...and quite frankly I hate working with NSDecimalNumber in Cocoa/iOS... so would rather not burrow down that path on a whim, unless there's some degree of certainty that NSDecimalNumber *is* the answer...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're submitting parameters as URL form-encoded in the query string; everything in a query string is a string.

Instead, you should send parameters as JSON. Set the `parameterEncoding` property of the HTTP client to AFJSONParameterEncoding, and everything should work as expected.

Comment: See my **edit** above. That's the way my shared AFHTTPClient subclass is being initiated. Perhaps `[self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding]` should be moved to another method?!?

Answer (score 0):

To send number you could use "AFJSONRequestSerializer"
for your manager. It solved my same problem

Answer (score -1):

JSON is pretty much limited to what can be expressed with JavaScript (since it's a subset), and JavaScript doesn't have support for big numbers past 53 bit floating points. Since doubles are normally 64 bits, these would get truncated during parsing if rendered as numbers, something you avoid when you render them as strings.

But this also means that it's up to your consuming code to convert back to doubles (or equivalent).

Comment: `double` has p=53 on most platforms including iOS; perhaps you're confusing it with `long double` which has p=64 on some platforms (but is the same as `double` or `double double` on others). I'm also pretty sure that the precision of JavaScript is unspecified.